# Looking for a Book to teach Statistics using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, statistics

I would like to revise University Statistics knowledge by reading a book that teaches Statistics using Excel (or any other free alternative spreadsheet) as the analysis tool.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Community Wiki perhaps

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, "statistics" often varies as there is (me not being an expert on the subject) mathematical statistics, statistics in economics, statistics in some biological sciences ... but anyways, assuming the first, here are a few recommendations:

[A Microsoft Excel Companion for Business Statistics (Paperback)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0324225539)
[The Excel Statistics Cookbook, Second Edition](http://www.lulu.com/content/381502)
[Statistical Analysis with Excel For Dummies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470454067) (do not take it the wrong way; they're good books)